# Is there provably a largest cardinal consistent with ZF

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-mathematics

In the integers:1,2,3... we can say that there isn't a largest number; but it turns out with the advent of set theory we can posit a largest number *omega* that doesn't lie within the integers and yet bounds them. In mathematical terms we can say that it is a *limit* to them.

Of course, with the advent of Cantorian set theory, it was also realised that one can define and investigate larger infinite numbers, which are ordinals and cardinals (cardinals are certain distinguished points in the ordinals and are very sparse). Then one can ask the same question at his new level: Is there a largest Cardinal?

Now, it turns out that [Reinhardt cardinals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinhardt_cardinal) are the largest cardinals yet defined in *ZFC*; To refine the question - are they provably the largest possible? Is there in fact provably, or conjecturally a largest cardinal wrt *ZFC*? (My intuition would say that there isn't).

(Choice is generally useful when dealing with properly infinitary objects, which is why I've asked with reference to ZFC, rather than ZF);

*NBG*, and *NFU* are alternative set theories that make formal use of a concept that *ZFC* informally uses, that is classes; as classes are not sets then formally the notion of cardinality or ordinality is applicable to them - but one could argue with judicious changes in the axioms that one could extend the notions to here; it would then seem a possibility of defining a class-cardinal that is the limit of all set-cardinals.

Is this this actually possible?

But then, one could argue that the same process could be iterated; in a much more profound sense the notion of mathematical infinity is always in *potentia*, though there are points at which we can say a certain *actuality* has been achieved (the limit points).

Is this a good argument?

Comment: -1 Sorry, but this is really a mathematical question and not related to phil of math.

Comment: @DBK: Admittedly it is phrased mathematically; but questions on infinity usually are seen as philosophical - are you saying that a question of that type isn't part of philosophy of mathematics as usually/professionally understood?

Comment: As you can see my observation referred to the first edit, which asked "Is there in fact provably, or conjecturally a largest cardinal wrt ZF?" The latter is simply a question about a mathematical fact/hypothesis. While we welcome questions *about philosophical implications of mathematical facts* (if there are any), questions about mathematical facts alone are off-topic and best asked on Math.SE (quite independently from the circumstance that there might be users who can answers math questions here as well).

Comment: @DBK: I altered the question given your critique as perhaps what i was asking wasn't easily visible.

Comment: Great, thanks! BTW, the cardinal hierarchy, i.e. large cardinals ordered by their consistency strength, clearly has an upper limit: **0=1** ;) (h/t to [Kanamori](http://books.google.at/books?id=FH_n84ocuSMC&lpg=PA460&ots=Fb0bLr6eiC&dq=cardinal%20hierarchy%20kanamori&pg=PA472#v=onepage&q=%22chart%20of%20cardinals%22&f=false))

Comment: @DBK:, but that doesn't explain anything to me. What do you mean, or Kanamori mean by 0=1? The link to the text is just a snippet, unfortunately. Perhaps you're referring to the [kunen inconsistency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinhardt_cardinal); but this shows that Reinhardt cardinals don't exist in NBG or ZF with choice; without choice, it appears possible. From this, it also appears that the Reinhardt cardinal is or *ought* to be the largest possible.

Comment: Never mind. It's a tongue-in-cheek answer, based on a nice "easter egg" in Kanamori's book. In the hierarchy, large cardinals can prove more and more, starting with the consistency of ZFC… until we reach 0=1, where we can prove everything :)

Comment: @DBK: well, 0=1 does actually define the trivial ring, generally ignored (until you get to the category of rings when its found to be important - like zero itself in a ring) so perhaps not so inconsistent after all :).

Answer (score 4):

Note that Reinhardt cardinals do *not* provably exist in ZFC. If they were, it would contradict Gödel's theorem. It is the largest cardinal currently defined which is believed to be **consistent** with ZFC.

As Mozibur notes, you can't have a largest such cardinal, since given a consistent extension of ZFC, you can always (in theory) find a stronger theory which proves the existence of larger cardinals. However, it may be found next week that Reinhard cardinals are actually *not* consistent with ZFC. That's the tragedy of the incompleteness theorem.

It turns out, however, that if ZFC is consistent, there is a **smallest** cardinal which is *not provably* such *in ZFC*. To show this, you can simply consider the set of all uniquely defined syntactic objects which ZFC proves to be cardinals, and take the smallest cardinal not in that set.

Edit: I missed the fact that Reinhardt cardinals are inconsistent with Choice. You can replace ZFC by ZF everywhere in my comment though, or Reinhardt cardinals by some smaller cardinal numbers ([superhuge](http://cantorsattic.info/Huge) for instance).

Comment: It’s open if it’s consistent with ZF but Kunen showed that Reinhardt cardinals contradict ZFC soon after they were proposed. Edit: I didn’t read the answer right below this which said the exact same thing

Comment: "It turns out, however, that if ZFC is consistent, there is a smallest cardinal which is not provably such in ZFC. To show this, you can simply consider the set of all uniquely defined syntactic objects which ZFC proves to be cardinals, and take the smallest cardinal not in that set." If I understand correctly, we have a model M of ZFC, which is presumably transitive, and you are taking the least cardinal which is not a cardinal in M (this is equal to ON∩M).

Comment: I don't think this is a strong argument to say there is a smallest cardinal which is not provably consistent in ZFC since this is not an intrinsic description of a cardinal property in M.

Comment: That's true, good point. One might consider the least $\lambda$ such that $V_\lambda$ is a model of ZFC, if the class of such things is non-empty. Though I'm not sure this is much better.

Answer (score 1):

There is no largest large cardinal axiom as there is no maximal consistent and recursive extension of ZFC.

Furthermore though there is a definition of a Reinhardt Cardinal, [However](http://cantorsattic.info/Kunen_inconsistency) that they don't exist:

> Shortly after this idea was introduced, however, Kunen famously proved that there are no such embeddings, and hence no Reinhardt cardinals in ZFC.

(In fact because of technical problems it was formulated in a class theory NBG and not ZFC, though there are work-arounds that allow it to work there).

This is formalised as the Kunen incocnsistency theorem, and shows that Reinhardt cardinals are inconsistent with Choice. In *ZF* or *NBG* it remains an open question.

[Hamkins et al](http://jdh.hamkins.org/generalizationsofkuneninconsistency/) show that the Kunen inconsistency is a natural limit in other ways, as many natural definitions of larger cardinals than the Reinhardt one also do not exist.

Comment: Just to add to this, for any large cardinal axiom $\phi$, you could always lump an extra inaccessible on top (so $\phi$ + there is an inaccessible above $\phi$) to obtain a strictly stronger axiom (in fact, by Godel $\phi + Con(\phi)$ will do).